# What is the result of boiling beer?

Tags: science

Recently, I had seen a video where a Coke was boiled, and end result was tar like substance.  I am just curious to know if anyone has tried boiling beer, and what is the result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I never tried such an heresy, but theoretically you will end up with some kind of syrup (or broth, I really don't know the most appropriate word in english for it), thick, and more or less sweet depending on the beer you use. Some beers have more residual sugars than other ones.

Alcohol will be the first to evaporate, then water, which is basically the majority of beers composition, in volume, leaving behind sugars and proteins, basically. Those last compounds can be modified or merged, as well, I can't say. Then, depending on the beer's malt bill (pale, crystal, caramelized, roasted, smoked, etc), you might get different flavors related to it. I don't know what would happen to hop compounds when boiled for a long time, but you'll probably still get some bitterness from them.

You know what, you question got me curious about how it would taste at the end. =P

Comment: I think in some dishes, beer powder might actually be really tasty. Now there's an idea!

Comment: @PieBie Dizzy Pig Barbecue Company makes an IPA rub that's pretty tasty. Not a beer powder exactly (ground hops are used), but evidence to support the general concept.

Comment: Maillard reaction, my friends. Bolied beer will taste more bready, cracker-like etc. And if it's high on sugar, it will end up with more caramel in it. Both are actually good in hot winter beer or in cooking.

Answer (score 4):

Beer reductions can make very good sauces.  For more flavor you go with [darker beers](http://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/blog/stout-beer-glaze-three-ways), but you apparently want to shy away from using hoppy beers because the bitterness can become rather harsh.  Just punch in something like "beer reduction" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: You can make a tasty beef stew with Guinness, or any IPA type beer.

Answer (score 2):

Beer will evaporate down when boiled. During this it will become thicker. The alcohol will evaporate the quickest, then the water. Caramelization (Maillard reaction) will occur. The bitterness will NOT evaporate, making the bitterness more concentrated.

However; boiling wort is "required" to make beer and excessive boiling is used in some styles to give it extra flavours and colours or to make the resulting beer stronger.

Answer (score -1):

Technically if you could reduce the water but not the alcohol you would then have a hard liquor. If you could later re-add carbonated water then you would have beer again.  It would likely loose some original flavor along the way.